# Load balancing netty websocketserver

Tags: netty, load-balancing

Recently I have tried out Netty server to develop a chat server. I have re-used the example "io.netty.http.example.websocketx.server", and modify it slightly by adding a channel map, message processor to save the new message to database, etc.

The channel map will contain all of the opened channels and the subscribed chatroom id. So when someone post some message to chatroom 123, upon receiving the messages in messageReceived function, the server will send the messages to all channels subscribed to that chatroom.

This method works fine when there's just 1 WebSocketServer instance, however, how can I load balance the load to multiple WebSocketServers? When the message is received by WebSocketServer #1, is there a way to notify WebSocketServer #2 to send the message to all of the subscribed users?

Comment: When a new channel joins a chatroom, is it a requirement that they receive a history of all messages posted to the chatroom, or only messages posted from that point on?

Comment: No need to see history, users will only receive new messages posted from that point onwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netty doesn't provide what you want out of the box.

As users only need to receive new messages you're looking for a distributed, non-persistent publish / subscribe system. You could create one yourself but two other options are

- use a JMS server. Each of your servers subscribes to a non persistent topic. They publish messages to the topic to broadcast to all other chat servers.
- embed [Hazelcast](http://hazelcast.org) and use its distributed topic mechanism for the same purpose. The advantage here is that you don't need to run a separate JMS server, each of your chat servers becomes a member of the cluster

In either scenario your chat server is receiving all messages all of the time and needs to filter appropriately. There are methods with both techniques where you can only receive the messages you're interested in if necessary (JMS selectors, different topics in hazelcast).

It might also be worth checking out [Vert.x](http://vertx.io) which is built on Netty and Hazelcast and provides a distributed event bus

Comment: Hi John, not sure if I understand it correctly. Would you mind to explain a bit more detail on how to use Hazelcast for this purpose? I can store the new message in the Hazelcast queue, however, that will mean that each websocket connection in different server will need to keep pooling to see if there's any new message available in hazelcast queue.

Comment: This is a bit theoretical as I haven't done it myself. Take a look at the topic example tab on http://hazelcast.org. You'll need to implement MessageListener and subscribe to the topic as shown. Hazelcast will call onMessage when a message arrives. The simplest implementation is that your onMessage implementation sends the message to each connected channel. Note hazelcast may drop messages if you can't keep up. Also, if writing the message to all channels takes some time, you might want to offload the actual write to another thread to avoid blocking the hazelcast thread for too long.